# Merge conflicts not shown

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, git-bash

I have a Maven project for automation for my application. I had to take a pull from master branch. In bash cmd prompt I got the message that the branches can't be merged because of conflicts in multiple files, but in eclipse it showed error only in one file which was currently open in eclipse. I had just installed the eclipse and git bash. Is there any other eclipse extension or something I need to download so that conflicts are shown in all the files?

Comment: Have you tried running `git status`? It should tell you the files the conflicts are

Comment: Eclipse contains a full-featured Git implementation. If you additionally use command line Git, you have to hit the _Refresh_ button e. g. in the _Git Staging_ or _Git Repository_ view.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not a problem with your eclipse, and you don't need any additional extensions/plugins in eclipse to get this working.

You might want to look at something called `git mergetool` [here](https://gist.github.com/karenyyng/f19ff75c60f18b4b8149).

You can get more info about `mergetool` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/163659/4014678).

You can find out about resolving `merge` conflicts [here](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/).

Comment: Do you recommend the use of command line tools although Eclipse contains a full-featured Git implementation? What are the reasons not to do merge within Eclipse?

Comment: I didn't recommend the use of cmd here since the OP asked if additional extensions were required for it to work, for which I replied it wasn't. In any case, `Egit` is an amazing tool to use here, makes life easy.